# SQL IN statement - keep duplicates when returning results

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have an sql query something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM prices WHERE item IN ('item1', 'item2', 'item2', 'item3');
```

Notice the duplicate value 'item2'.
I want the query to return the value for that item as many times as it appears in the IN clause. By default it only returns once. How can I do that?

Comment: the query is correct. it means your `prices` table has only one row for `item2`. To check, do a `count(*)` on the table to see how many rows it has for each item.

Comment: There's no need to repeat `'item2'` within the IN clause.

Comment: Which two do you want to return? What if there are three of them to pick from?

Answer (score 4):

Then you need to use `left join`:

```
select p.*
from (select 'item1' as item union all select 'item2' union all
      select 'item2' union all select 'item3'
     ) i left join
     prices p
     on i.item = p.item;
```

Comment: Could you Select * from prices where item in (1,2,3) UNION ALL Select * from prices where item = 2?

Answer (score 4):

SQL treats items of the `IN` list as a set, ignoring the duplicates.

In databases that support table-valued parameters (TVP) you could replace `IN` with an inner join on a TVP, but MySQL does not offer them.

An alternative approach would be to populate a temporary table with the items from your `IN` list, and query with an inner join against it:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE InList (item varchar(10)); 
INSERT INTO InList(item) VALUES ('item1');
INSERT INTO InList(item) VALUES ('item2');
INSERT INTO InList(item) VALUES ('item2');
INSERT INTO InList(item) VALUES ('item3');
```

Now your query would look like this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM prices p
INNER JOIN InList i ON i.item = p.item
```

Since joining produces a Cartesian product, rows of `price` would be repeated as many times as they are listed in the temporary `InList` table.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The query will return the number of times `item1` appears in the table, not the number of times it appears in your query

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is look for the number of times each item is present, and then check for the number you want, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM prices po WHERE
EXISTS (SELECT item FROM prices pi
        WHERE pi.item = po.item
        GROUP BY item
        HAVING ( (COUNT(item) = 1 AND item in ('item1', 'item3') )
            OR ( (COUNT(item) = 2 AND item = 'item2' )
       )
```

Since this will return all matches, you will get each item showing up in the result the number of times it appears in the prices table.

Two notes on Gordon's answer (since I'm new here and can't comment there):
(1) The left outer join could cause nulls to be returned. If item3 does not appear in prices at all, then a null will appear in the result. You can use a filter (where p.item is not null) to remove those nulls. 
(2) If item2 appears only once in prices table, the join will still make it appear twice in the result. The join doesn't perform a check that item2 appears twice in price, it just joins it twice to the constant table created in the FROM clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM PRICE
WHERE ITEM IN (item1, item2, item3)

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM PRICE
WHERE ITEM = item2
```