# SQL Repeat primary key row in the select statement without using union all function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I want to select the records from the table having primary key column in the table. but I want repeated records of primary key based on the dynamic input given to the query.

Suppose I have employee table with two columns: `(emp_id (primary key), emp_name);`

```
emp_id   name
 1       abc 
 2       xy
 3       xyz
```

And suppose I am selecting records from emp table like.

```
Select * from emp where emp_id in (1,2,2,3);
```

Three rows will be returned from the table.
Instead of three, I want to retrieve 4 rows from the table.

The query should also work for the other inputs like:

```sql
Select * from emp where emp_id in (1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3);
```

at that time also I should return the 9 rows from table.

I have already tried with `union all` function to retrieve the records.
But `union all` will be a static solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL IN statement - keep duplicates when returning results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33835516/sql-in-statement-keep-duplicates-when-returning-results)

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: I am using SqlServer.

Comment: Please also mention the version.

Comment: Its SqlServer 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a dataset using `VALUES` and join it to the table:

```
with cte as (
  select * from
  (values (1),(1),(1),(2),(2),(3),(3),(3),(3)) as t(id)
)
select e.* 
from cte c inner join emp e
on e.emp_id = c.id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=4f25c7b2ffd0a8daaa5b51e3a9ed540a).
Results:

```
> emp_id | name
> -----: | :---
>      1 | abc 
>      1 | abc 
>      1 | abc 
>      2 | xy  
>      2 | xy  
>      3 | xyz 
>      3 | xyz 
>      3 | xyz 
>      3 | xyz
```

Comment: Thank you so much, its working fine. you are a genius.

Comment: @JaypalSodha the answer you got is correct. See the demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fdca4856f195c66d51d43da2a37176b0 Isn't this that you want?

Comment: yes its working fine, I want making mistake writing the query in my editor.
Thank you so much, you guys are awesom.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to guarantee the ordering of the result set, then you need to include that information in the `value()` clause:

```
select v.id, e.* 
from (values (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 2),
             (5, 2), (6, 3), (7, 3), (8, 3), (9, 3)
     ) v(ord, id) left join
     emp e
     on e.emp_id = v.id
order by v.ord;
```

Notes:

- You do not need a subquery or CTE for the values clause.  It seems redundant.
- The `left join` ensures that the exact rows are in the result set *even when there are no matches*.  For this reason, it includes the id from the derived table.
- The `order by` is needed to guarantee the ordering.

Comment: @@Gordon Linoff Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this as you mentioned you are using SQL Server version 2016 (compatibility level of 130 is required)-

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT value 
    FROM STRING_SPLIT('1,2,2,3', ',')
)A
LEFT JOIN your_table B ON A.value = B.emp_id
```

You can check [DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=5e9f61ea2c1ef4072d66a735b321f80d)

Comment: can you please help me with this question,https://stackoverflow.com/q/57482171/5874233

Comment: Ok, I am checking.

Comment: @JaypalSodha I have posted an answer in that question. Please check.

Comment: its working fine sir, and thank you so much for your help. :)

Comment: @JaypalSodha you are most welcome. Please accept that answer and give an up vote :)