# Finding top 3 students from the Student table and Department table group by department

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Suppose we have two Tables:
1. Student
2. Department

```
  Student table has 4 columns 
   1. id (int pk)
   2. name (varchar)
   3. percentage (int)
   4. dept_id (fk)

  Department table has 3 columns
   1. dept_id (int pk)
   2. dept_name (varchar)
```

Query is to select top 3 students from the each department having highest percentage.

I have already written the query with row_num() function.

But, I am facing problem when there are students with the same percentage.

```
Student table with:
id  name   percentage  dept_id
1   a      70          1
2   b      80          1 
3   c      90          1 
4   d      70          1
5   e      55          1 
6   f      50          2
7   g      65          2
8   h      68          2   

Department table with 

dept_id  dept_name 
1        Information Technology
2        Computer Science


**expected Result**

id  student_name  dept_name                percentage  row_number
3   c             Information Technology   90          1
2   b             Information Technology   80          2
1   a             Information Technology   70          3  
4   d             Information Technology   70          4
8   h             Computer Science         68          5 
7   g             Computer Science         65          6
6   f             Computer Science         50          7
```

you can see that, there are two student with 70% so both the student will be considered at the third place, and will be a part of top 3.

I have tried something like

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUM() OVER (PARTITION BY D.Dept_ID ORDER BY S.PERCENTAGE DESC) AS ROW_NUMBER
   FROM STUDENT S, DEPARTMENT D WHERE D.DEPT_ID = S.DEPT_ID
)
SELECT ID, NAME AS STUDENT_NAME, DEPT_NAME, PERCENTAGE FROM CTE WHERE ROW_NUMBER < 4.
```

HERE, I am adding static condition (row_number < 4) row_number, It will give me a wrong output when there are students with the same percentage.

Please help with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this the query you are trying to write?

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT s.ID, s.NAME, d.DEPT_NAME, s.PERCENTAGE,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY D.Dept_ID ORDER BY S.PERCENTAGE DESC) AS seqnum
   FROM STUDENT S JOIN
        DEPARTMENT D
       ON  D.DEPT_ID = S.DEPT_ID
)
SELECT cte.ID, cte.NAME AS STUDENT_NAME, cte.DEPT_NAME, cte.PERCENTAGE
FROM CTE
WHERE seqnum < 4;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- `ROW_RANK()` is not a function.  I think you want `RANK()`, given that you want four rows when the limit is just 3.

Comment: Actually this query will work fine, If there are not duplicate percentage in the datatbase, but when there are multiple students with the same percentage, then all those should be at the same place. And that scnerio won't work here.

Comment: sir, please help

Comment: @JaypalSodha Gordon's answer should give you the results you want, if there is something missing, please update your question with the scenario (cases) that this answer didn't cover.  (update your examples/ expected output as well).

Answer (score 1):

You can try with DENSE_RANK() instead off ROW_NUMBER() as below-

```
SELECT A.dept_id,A.name,A.dept_name,A.percentage 
FROM
(
    SELECT D.dept_id,S.name,D.dept_name,S.percentage,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY D.dept_id ORDER BY S.[percentage] DESC) RN
    FROM Department D
    INNER JOIN Student S ON D.dept_id = S.dept_id
)A 
WHERE RN <= 3
```

Output is-

```
dept_id name    dept_name               percentage
1       c       Information Technology  90
1       b       Information Technology  80
1       d       Information Technology  70
1       a       Information Technology  70
2       h       Computer Science        68
2       g       Computer Science        65
2       f       Computer Science        50
```